# spring boot how to invoke the newly fixed bug version?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using spring boot `1.2.5.RELEASE`, and I use `spring-boot-starter-redis`.

But I found a bug on `spring-boot-starter-redis`, and spring-boot already fixed it.

The bug is here :

[Version 1.6 GA (Gosling)](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS/fixforversion/15278/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel)

[spring data redis starter exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3957#issuecomment-140015088)

[Upgrade to Spring Data Gosling RELEASE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3860)

Now Can I use the fixed version `Version 1.6 GA` in `1.2.5.RELEASE` ? 
If not what should I do ?

below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>tradove-backend-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>mycompany-redis</module>
    <module>mycompany-common</module>
    <module>mycompany-email</module>
    <module>mycompany-file-system</module>
    <module>mycompany-domain</module>
    <module>mycompany-service</module>
    <module>mycompany-solr</module>
    <module>mycompany-sms</module>
</modules>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>local private nexus</name>
        <url>http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>local private nexus</name>
        <url>http://maven.oschina.net/content/groups/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- data jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hateos -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- data redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- data solr-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot gets the version of all of the Spring Data modules by importing the bom for the Spring Data release train. To upgrade to the Gosling release train, which contains Spring Data Redis 1.6, override the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` property in your pom:

```
<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: I should put the content to where, pom.xml?